# why in the case of electric field the path of electrons is curved?

Tags: electric-current

I was wondering ,that why  in the presence of uniform electric field the electrons are moving in a curved path.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the forces involved and solving the two differential equations (one for $x$ and one for $y$)?

Comment: It is the same as a thrown rock following a curved path in a uniform gravitational field.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to moving in a curved path is moving in a straight path. Which your electron will only do only if all the forces are parallel to its velocity vector. So an electron starting from rest in a uniform electric field will travel in a straight line - but that is an exception, not the rule. But you could think of that as a "curved path with infinite radius of curvature".

Comment: Yes. To add on to this and help visualise it, the electrons will only _accelerate_ in a straight line path if they are projected into the uniform electric field along the direction of the field lines. Notice, I am using the word _accelerate_ in italics because if we look at the equation for the electrons path in a uniform field the nature of such an equation (being an x^2 equation means it is parabolic, and as such y is proportional to x^2) the direction along which is the Y-axis (at right angles to the field lines) it is at constant velocity, wheras parralel to the field lines it is accelerat

Comment: ...ing. (whoops, should watch the character count next time). So perpendicularly (to the field lines) it will be accelerating due to the change in direction.

Answer (score 1):

The electrons are not moving in a *curved* path. They are moving according to the solutions of the Newton's equation 
$$
m\textbf{a}=\textbf{F}(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')=q\,\textbf{E}(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')
$$
As the above being a Cauchy problem, the form of its general solution explicitly depends on the initial conditions for position and velocity and in general the only way that can give back a straight line is that the particle is starting at rest and the force is constant. But these considerations are true for **all** mechanical systems, not only for electrons in an electric field.